# Arduino static variable declaration with no datatype?

Tags: c++, c, variables, definition

I am quite new to Arduino and try to understand the following variable declaration:

```
static btn_state_t nav_btn, joy_btn;
```

First, I would expect a datatype like integer or float or the like after "static".
I only found one answer that the variable then would be assigned a default type?
Second, I don't understand the following comma-separated "names" or other variables.
In the programm, it looks like they can be both used for "btn_state_t".

I couldn't find an answer to my question so far...or maybe someone can give me a hint on what search-words to look for?

Thanks Steve for the profound and complete answer below! Compleatly answered my question and his guessing was right ...that even with quite some search, I didn't find that datatype and "typedef" was the right codeword.
So solved for me.

Comment: `btn_state_t` is a type.

Comment: `nav_btn` and `joy_btn` are two static variables of type `btn_state_t`. The syntax is similar to`static int i, j;`

Comment: Trying to learn C by trial&error is know to cause depressions. Do not do that. Read a book, take a course ...

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: `btn_state_t` is a type, and you're declaring two variables of this type.

---

Longer answer:

If you said

```
int nav_btn, joy_btn;
```

you would be declaring two variables of type `int`.  The type name is `int` and the names of the variables are `nav_btn` and `joy_btn`.

If you said

```
static int nav_btn, joy_btn;
```

you would be doing the same thing, but declaring them statically.  (This can have two different meanings, depending on whether the declaration is inside or outside a function, but let's not worry about that just now.)  In this declaration, the keyword `static` is known as a *storage class*.

Once upon a time, things defaulted to `int` a lot.  Therefore, you could also say

```
static nav_btn, joy_btn;
```

This has a storage class `static` and two variable names `nav_btn` and `joy_btn`, but no type name.  But it ends up doing the same thing, declaring two static variables of type `int`, because originally in C, the missing type name defaulted to `int`.  This style of declaration is obsolete today.  But that's what the other answer you found was talking about.

But you've stumbled across another case.  You have

```
static btn_state_t nav_btn, joy_btn;
```

If there were a comma between `btn_state_t` and `nav_btn` this would be a declaration of three static variables with their type defaulted to `int`.  But there isn't a comma, and there's that little clue `_t` in `btn_state_t`.  It turns out that `btn_state_t` is the name of a type.

So this is a declaration of two static variables, of type `btn_state_t`, named `nav_btn` and `joy_btn`.

But what's this type name `btn_state_t`?  Obviously you won't find it in any list of C types, along with `int` and `long int` and `double` and the rest.  And the answer is that it's an example of a *typedef*.

Somewhere, in a project-specific header file, or the header file for a GUI or I/O library you're using, is probably a line like

```
typedef int btn_state_t;
```

This line *defines a new type name*.  The new type name is `btn_state_t`, and the type it names is otherwise identical to type `int`.  Now when you type

```
btn_state_t btn;
```

or

```
btn_state_t nav_btn, joy_btn;
```

it's just as if you had said

```
int btn;
int nav_btn, joy_btn;
```

In other words, `typedef` is sort of like `#define`.  Saying

```
typedef int btn_state_t;
```

is sort of like saying

```
#define btn_state_t int
```

Afterwards, every time we write `btn_state_t`, it's just as if we'd written `int`.  (But in more complicated cases, `typedef` can do things that `#define` can't, so they're really not at all the same mechanism.)

Typedefs are a powerful mechanism, but it's always a little surprising to have new type names floating around that you've never heard of, so there's a convention of always using the suffix `_t` in a typedef name.  Other common examples of such typedefs are type names like `size_t` and `time_t` and `int32_t`.

If you've never encountered typedefs before, you may be wondering what they're good for.  You may be wondering why they're necessary, since at first it looks like good old `#define` would work just fine.  And you may be wondering what the point is, since you could always just say

```
static int nav_btn, joy_btn;
```

if the "real" type behind `btn_state_t` is in fact `int`.  But this answer is too long already, so if you're still curious about `typedef`, I'll just encourage you to do a web search on it and read about it.